# Create random numbers within a range?

Tags: actionscript-3

What's a simple way to generate random numbers with a range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work?

```
private function randRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}
```

Comment: Note that this only returns integers instead of the full range of Number.

Answer (score 3):

use [Math.random](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Math.html#random%28%29) function that return n such as 0.0 <= n < 1.0

so this one return n such as min<= n< max

```
   function random(min:Number, max:Number):Number {
     return Math.random()*(max-min)+min;
    }
```

if you want to include the max range look at this [one](http://snipplr.com/view/7326/as3-random-range/)